# Varnish & ESIs : Fetching in parallel and possible workarounds

Tags: caching, memcached, reverse-proxy, varnish, esi

I'm investigating using Varnish with ESIs to cache page content for a high traffic forum-like website.

Context : I want to cache content for visitors only (connected users will have a really different display and need absolute fresh content). Still, for visitors, some parts of a page need to be dynamic : 
- not cachable, for example for a visitor-dependant module (think a 'suggestion' widget that is fed with a real-time analysis of the pages viewed, thanks to a beacon)
- cachable with a small TTL of 15mn, for example for a 'latest posts' widget or for very changing ads campaigns.

Currently we are using Apache/PHP/symfony/memcache to cache pages and have in-house ESI-like mecanism : a page from cache is parsed and some specific tags are interpreted (including calls to web services and/or databases). This is not performant enough since server time is then around 700ms.

In remplacement of this solution, we can have Varnish+ESIs. The total nb of ESIs included in a page can reach 15. The real number of ESIs to fetch will be less than that but not so much given the ESI's TTLs. The critical problem is that Varnish fetches the ESIs sequencially instead of parallel and this is not acceptable. This feature is somewhere late in Varnish's roadmap.

So,

- What is your experience with Varnish and ESIs ? How many ESIs, response time gain that you have ?
- Do you know workarounds or other serious and configurable (VCL was nice) reverse-proxies with parallel ESI fetching ?
- If not, what kind of good caching strategy do you use for equivalent use-cases ?

Thanks,
P.

Comment: *15* ESI includes? That's rather an insane number. You cannot rearrange those into a smaller number of groups and position them with CSS?

Comment: Not really, pages have a lot of dynamic content coming from different data sources with different TTLs (think several ad zones, recommendations, user module, ...)

Comment: Looking at this question again (now that you poked me): This is too open and vague a question for Stack Overflow (see the [FAQ#dontask]); tightened up to focus on specific aspects it *may* be on-topic on Server Fault (but check their FAQ first).

Answer (score 1):

Currently i work for a high traffic site, and performance is everything for us. On several pages we use a lot (20+) of ESI's, for example on our search resultlist. The resultlist is JSON response, and every resultblock in it is a seperate ESI. Okay, we do cache warming. But we didn't run in any performance issues on this. The number of ESI's will be a problem if the backend requests are real slow.

Parallel ESI fetching is on the feature request list of Varnish, but i think it didn't make it in version 4.1.